# How to change a message which user of a bot see after /start command is inputted?

Tags: command, telegram-bot

I have tried to use commands /setdescription and /setabouttext but with no result. Users see a message when they input command /start and this message looks like a message I used when bot was added initially. Please advise how to change it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The response to "/start" command is generated by bot itself.

So you need to change your bot's code to return whatever you want. For example in my bot I check if user was seen by the bot before (registered) and if not ask users to choose preferred language.